# An elegant way to find diff of two list of objects in Java

Tags: java

This is the simplest possible implementation.

The two lists will contain at max, 3-5 elements, so the size of lists is not a matter of concern.

Any recommendation on how can I make this pretty?

```
private ListsHolder findDiffOfLists(List<MyObject> objsFromDB, List<MyObjRequest> objsFromRequest) {
    ListsHolder holder = this.new ListsHolder(); //An object holding two lists

    for(MyObjRequest req_obj : objsFromRequest){
        boolean isAdded = false;
        for(MyObject db_obj : objsFromDB){
            if(isSameObj(db_obj, req_obj)){
                db_obj.setVal(req_obj.getVal()); //Set new value
                holder.matchingObjList.add(db_obj);
                isAdded = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isAdded){
            holder.newObjList.add(req_obj); //If element does not exist
        }
    }

    return holder;
}

private boolean isSameObj(MyObject db_obj, MyObjRequest req_obj) {
       return req_obj.getMatch().equals(db_obj.getMatch());
}
```

Comment: It there an hierarchical relation between MyObject and MyObjectRequest?

Comment: no there is no relation between the two objects. They are completely different, just have some values common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create this method:

```
private MyObject findMatch(List<MyObject> objsFromDB, MyObjRequest req_obj){
    for(MyObject db_obj : objsFromDB){
        if(isSameObj(db_obj, req_obj)){
            return db_obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and refactor accordingly.

Beyond that the only suggestion I would have is perhaps some better variable names (at least use a single naming style; if you don't already have one, use this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: I have proper styles in my actual code, had to obfuscate the code before posting here :) But I agree, I will update my question. Btw, returning `null` is a good practice?

Comment: I am not actually a java developer, but I don't see why it would be bad. Certainly it would not be as bad as doing extra work (iterating over the rest of the loop) when you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to move the `isSameObj` inside the `MyObject` class as it deals with the attributes inside that object. You can override the `equals` method of `MyObject` so that the `equals` method in `MyObject` will be like

```
boolean equals(MyObject target){
    return this.getMatch().equals(target.getMatch());
}
```

and the original code will become like

`if(db_obj.equals(req_obj))` instead of `if(isSameObj(db_obj, req_obj))`

Comment: In other words see: Law of Demeter (req_obj.getMatch().equals() is a violation)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a variation of Bill Barry's answer. Don't really see the need to return the object, when we already know it. It's a simple test function, which means you expect to get true or false from it:

```
private boolean isMatch(List<MyObject> objsFromDB, MyObjRequest req_obj){
    for(MyObject db_obj : objsFromDB){
        if(isSameObj(db_obj, req_obj)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This way you don't have to have another check to see if the value returned by the function is NULL or not.